# java.library.path not set correctly from runtime.exec/ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I have a java-based application launcher that uses `ProcessBuilder` (have tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{}` as well) that launches another java application via a command.

When I run the command manually, it works properly. The game launches, no errors.

`java -jar -Djava.library.path="./lib/natives" mygame.jar`

When the same command (with absolute paths) is run from the launcher:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "java",
        "-jar",
        "-Djava.library.path=\"" +nativesDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
        applicationJar.getAbsolutePath());
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.directory(applicationDirectory);
```

I see the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path`

I've tried multiple variations but it just seems like the command will never properly set the library path when being run from the java launcher.

1. Is there anything else I can try? Why would the command work for me, but not the launcher? I've tried the ProcessBuilder because I was worried it might be problems with spaces in the file paths (despite having quotes around it)
2. Is there a better way to let my application dictate/discover where the libs/native files are, avoiding having to always pass the argument anyway?

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes around the path?  The quotes are parsed by the shell and are not necessary when spawning a process directly from Java.

Comment: That solved it... holy cow. If you want to move this to an answer I'll mark it. I can't believe no one else I've spoken to suggested that, myself included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you remove the quotes around the path? The quotes are parsed by the shell and are not necessary when spawning a process directly from Java.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can add path to the native library to PATH env variable thru ProcessBuilder.environment()

Comment: Thanks, gave it a try but nothing changed. I appended the natives directory to the existing path, and then add it via `pb.environment().put("PATH", fullPath);`. I even iterated the pb.environment map to confirm. Same error on startup. Tried the path with and without the quotes.